# setBackgroundcolor with a Parameter

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jtextfield

I'm trying to create a little GUI with the MVC-Structure, now I want be able to set the background of a JTextField in my GUI from the Listener Class:

```
package gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Date;

public class Gui extends JFrame {

    private JTextField jtf;
    private JLabel lblStatus;


    public Gui() {
        new JFrame();
        jtf = new JTextField();
        //jtf.addKeyListener(this);
        lblStatus = new JLabel("Zeit:");

        setSize(700, 60);
        setTitle("Tippmaster V1.0");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        add(jtf);
        add(lblStatus);
        setVisible(true);

    }
    public void addKeyListener(KeyListener kl){
        jtf.addKeyListener(kl);

    public void setStatus(String status){
        lblStatus.setText(status);
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param color should involve the information of the color for example GREEN
    */
    public void setBackgroundcolor(Color color){
        jtf.setBackground(Color.color);
    }

}
```

So I cant write in the Listener Class only:

```
package controller;

import gui.Gui;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

/**
 * Created by tq67 on 23.07.2014.
 */
public class CharListener implements KeyListener {

    private Gui gui;

    public CharListener(Gui gui) {
        this.gui = gui;

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {      /* Nothing to do */        }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

            //Here I want to set the parameter sth like this or maybe only Green Blue etc..
            gui.setBackground(Color.GREEN);     
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {       /* Nothing to do */        }
}
```

Is that possible or should I give a String as a Parameter and parse it in the GUI Class?
Thx for your help!

Comment: *"String as Parameter an parse it in the GUI Class?"*  Pass a `Color` if that is what it is supposed to represent!

Comment: i made some tippmistakes... just updated it..

Comment: Have you thought about `JColorChooser` [How to Use Color Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html)?

Comment: Again, I'd parse a `String` to a `Color` at the first possible opportunity, and especially agree with the suggestion of @DavidPostill - no better (Swing) component for choosing a color than a `JColorChooser`.

Comment: okey i must see i heard the JColorChooser is a bit too large for my little gui^^

Comment: but I think I found the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem by myself:

Because I send a Color Object as a Parameter so I must only write:

```
public void setBackgroundcolor(Color color){
    jtf.setBackground(color);
}
```